# save_post_post-type WordPress Hook, only works when i create a new post but it doesnt work when i edit a post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-hook

I have a Custom Post Type "Compania", it has a meta field called "compania_id" i would like that field = current post_id

I implemented this action to do that and it works when i create a new post (compania_id automatically is equal to current post_id) but in older compania post when this code hasnt been created, when i edit these post and save, compania_id isnt filled with the post_id as when i create a new post, why??

```
function anadir_post_id($post_id){
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'compania_id', $post_id);
}
add_action( 'save_post_compania', 'anadir_post_id', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Look at the docs. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/ check out the third param.

Answer (score 1):

The [hook you use](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/) has three parameters.  Therefore your code needs to look like this.

```php
function anadir_post_id( int $post_ID, WP_Post $post, bool $update ){
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'compania_id', $post_id );
}
add_action( 'save_post_compania', 'anadir_post_id', 10, 3 ); //<--- 3 params!
```

If you have an older version of php it will look like this:

```php
function anadir_post_id( $post_ID, WP_$post, $update ){
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'compania_id', $post_id );
}
add_action( 'save_post_compania', 'anadir_post_id', 10, 3 ); //<--- 3 params!
```

And, of course, if you have access to a post's `wp_postmeta` rows, you already know its `ID`. What you store here may be redundant.

Comment: I update the code but the issue persists, when i update the post and erase/change compania_id value, the post ID is never re-assigned to company_id